# When will Findbugs 3.0.0 FINAL be released?

Tags: java-8, findbugs, sonarqube

My understanding is that Findbugs 3.0.0 will support analyzing Java 8 bytecode. I see that there is a beta version of it available here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/findbugs/files/findbugs/3.0.0/

SonarQube is waiting until the final version of Findbugs 3.0.0 is released before upgrading their Java plugin to use it. This means SonarQube is unable to analyze our Java 8 projects.

Is there a target date for Findbugs 3.0.0 release or a known workaround for using the beta version of it with SonarQube?

Comment: There is some discussion around this on the FB-Discuss list currently, but I haven't seen a date mentioned yet. You may wish to join the list (it's fairly low-volume) in order to lobby for it's release (or help out, even :-)). https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/mailman/listinfo/findbugs-discuss

Comment: Thanks @Disco3. Somehow I missed that mailing list.

Comment: Your question is more than legit and in fact I also pushed on that mailing list to get a 3.0.RC1 released.

Comment: Just so you know. Release of findbugs is done and we have just launched the vote for sonar-findbugs-plugin embedding version 3.0 on mailing list : http://markmail.org/message/xn7cxittgfn52n7c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, 3.0.0 RC1 is released today (25.06.2014) and we plan to release 3.0.0 final (if there will be no major regressions reported) in July.

**Update: 3.0.0 is released** on 06.07.2014, see https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2014-July/004029.html

Comment: 3.0.0 is out - when will it it hit maven repos?

Comment: It is being deployed and will appear there in the next few hours (or days). See https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2014-July/004054.html

Answer (score 1):

As per mailing list thread : https://mailman.cs.umd.edu/pipermail/findbugs-discuss/2014-May/003999.html

The release is now mainly depending on early adopters feedback.